# SQL query group by multiple time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
SalesDate smalldatetime,
ProductId varchar(20),
QuantitySold tinyint,
Price smallmoney
```

I want to get the last 1m, 3m, 1y total quantity sold for each product.  How do I do that in one query?  My attempt so far is to run three separate queries, one for each time period, and then combine them using UNION.  Is there a better way?  I am using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: No, if you want them stacked vertically, then UNION is the best way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can more easily do this with multiple columns:

```
select productId,
       sum(case when salesdate >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) then quantitysold else 0 end) as qs1m,
       sum(case when salesdate >= dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) then quantitysold else 0 end) as qs3m
       sum(case when salesdate >= dateadd(month, -12, getdate()) then quantitysold else 0 end) as qs12m
from table t
group by productId;
```

(Note:  You probably want to at least remove the times from `getdate()`, but you might have an entirely different way of getting the "as-of" date.)

Because the time periods overlap, it is easier to do this with columns (and conditional aggregation) than with a separate row for each time period.

Comment: If "last year" actually means current year (often a requirement) use `case when year(salesdate) = year(getdate()) then...`.

Comment: Probably worth adding `WHERE salesdate >= DateAdd(mm, -12, Current_Timestamp)` to the query too.